# How to pass( Windows credantial) authentication from site A to site B (Publish with Windows authentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 publish website A and B.

B site with windows authentication

I want to open B site as new window from A site, so its ask for windows credential.  I have credential in A site. I am opening B site using Javascript.window.open.

Can you pls guide me how i can set window credential for B site from A site.

or is any other way to achieve this.

Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the way is make use of **HttpModule and Impersonation** if your site B is desinged using Asp.net +  C#

here is the solution : [**`HttpModule, Authentication and impersonation!`**](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/visual-studio/7/30172/httpmodule-authentication-and-impersonation.aspx) might resolve your issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because the Windows Authentication is handled by IIS, and no longer by your application. The only thing you can do however, is to use the information from site A on site B by passing it through a cookie.

This requires however:
- both sites using the same encryption settings
- the same encryption/decryption algorithm used by both sites.

This way allows you to send out an HTTP Auth challenge from site A, requesting the user to enter his Windows credentials, which are then validated by IIS. If this succeeds, your Identity property on the context will be set.

When this happens, store the information in a cookie, reload the cookie from site B and use tha information to authenticate the user in website B.
That's how we allow both Forms Auth & Windows Auth on a single website, but it can also be used to perform the mechanism you want.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where site B is located relatively to site A. If in the same domain and you're using windows auth you should be fine authenticating the same way as for site B.